# Using for loop with summarise and dplyr

Tags: r, for-loop

first time posting!

I'll start with the main problem:

dummy data:

```
df <- data.frame(target = c('0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1'), 
                 id = c('1', '2', '5', '63', '67', '77'),
                 feature1= c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                 feature2=c(6,6,6,6,6,6),
                 feature3=c(2,2,2,2,2,2), 
                 feature4=c(5,5,5,5,5,5))



for (col in names(df)[3:6]) {
  df %>% group_by(target) %>% 
    summarise(col=boxplot((col))$out)
}
```

**Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `col`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i Input `col` is `boxplot((col))$out`.
i The error occurred in group 1: target = 0.**

**I can't for loop the pipe written above. Context below:**

I've written this piece of code and it's working quite well. The main idea is to remove outliers from my dataframe, column wise and grouped by target, and then plot a set of boxplots for each featureX (there are many) varying target and each feature's values.

```
#get id where median is an outlier (in relation to a boxplot built with id medians
u1<-df %>%
  group_by(target,id) %>%
      summarise_all(median)  %>%
        group_by(target) %>% 
           summarise(feature1=boxplot.stats(feature1)$out)

b<-df %>%
  group_by(target,id) %>%
      summarise_all(median)   

u1<-inner_join(u1, b, by = c("feature1", "target"))[1:3]

f<-subset(df, !(id %in% u1$id))#[c(1,2,3)]
f<-as.data.frame(f)

ggplot(f)+geom_boxplot(aes(as.factor(target),feature1,fill=as.factor(target)))
```

So I just want to run this last piece of code and produce X plots for each featureX

Looked very hard but couldn't find any help!

Comment: Please provide reproducible data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are functions available in `dplyr` to apply a function to multiple columns.

Using `across` you can set outliers in each feature column for each group to `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>%
        group_by(target) %>%
        summarise(across(starts_with('feature'), 
                         ~replace(., .%in% boxplot(.)$out, NA)))
```

If you don't have `dplyr` updated to 1.0.0 or higher you can use `summarise_at` as :

```
df1 <- df %>%
        group_by(target) %>%
        summarise_at(vars(starts_with('feature')), 
                         ~replace(., .%in% boxplot(.)$out, NA))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! I was missing the syntax of using . instead of col in a for loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this

```
for (col in names(df)[3:6]) {
  df %>% 
    group_by(target) %>% 
    summarise(!!col := boxplot(.data[[col]])$out)
}
```